# Corda Node H2 illegal State Exception

Tags: h2, corda

we are having an issue in one of our corda nodes, everytime we try to restart we see following error:

[1;31mE 08:18:33-0400 [Node thread-1] spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This store is closed

Additinoally if I tried to access to node H2 DB in Internet Explorer I get this error message: 90047BVersion mismatch, driver version is "0" but server version is "16"ÿÿÿÿ_¿\org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Version mismatch, driver version is "0" but server version is "16" [90047-194] at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:89) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any idea about rca of this issue?

Thanks!!

Javier

Comment: Based on [other reports](http://h2-database.66688.n3.nabble.com/h2-database-possible-corruption-issue-td4032760.html) of "IllegalStateException: This store is closed" it sounds like your database is corrupted, and there might be some information in a .trace file next to the database? Or [some other reports](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/373#issuecomment-252470923) have a 'Caused by' exception with specific details of the error if you can find that? Alas I don't know h2 well enough to say if or how you can recover this.

Comment: As Rup says, can you see if there is some kind of exception further up in the logs related to H2?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to run this queryableState CorDapp [samples](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Features/queryablestate-carinsurance). The H2 database seems working fine.

I would suggest you check your log to see if there is any error message during the deployNodes process. Just in case, there is something wrong with the java environment.